# Java Chart Lib (with good documentation)

Tags: java, library, charts

I'm currently using a self-coded bar chart implementation with Java (swift), which worked fine up until now. But as my project grows, so do my requirements… As a result, I would like to start using a Java library that offers more chart formats than my own implementation.

What I need:

- bar charts
- pie charts
- scatter plots

and, last but not least

- good documentation

Looking around on the internet, I did find [JFreeChart](http://jfree.org) – but something tells me it might not be the only option out there, and I surely don't want to make the mistake of picking what I find first, if there is something more recommendable out there.

Which Java library (or libraries) would you recommend for charts?

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 more pointers to lists of charting libraries:

- [Charting libraries](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#supportedlibraries) used as charting engines in various contributed [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) modules (disclosure: I'm the original author of this page).
- The question about "[Graph visualization library in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-library-in-javascript)", which includes many links to charting libraries also.

Up to you to further investigate which of these libraries might possibly be considered as a valid alternative in your case. While investigating, make sure to also consider the actual license (open source, commercial, etc) for those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

## Vaadin

Inside a [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) web app, I have found the [Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts) add-on very useful. While open-source, this tool is a commercial product requiring a fee.

Vaadin Charts meets your requirements, but is only relevant for use inside of Vaadin-based web app.

Vaadin is a server-side tool for writing a web app in pure Java on the server-side. Then Vaadin automatically generates HTML/CSS/JavaScript to render your app on the client-side in the web browser.

## HighCharts (JavaScript)

That Vaadin Charts product is built on top of the [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) library written in JavaScript. This too is a commercial product requiring a fee.

This might be useful to you if there were some way to [A] run JavaScript within your app for live interactive charts, or [B] run JavaScript in the background to generate static images.